# Testing the Output it Says its Terminated

Tags: java, output

The Code below I tried got to work correctly. When I go to "Run As" in Eclipse, the Console shows nothing and the output is blank. Please help. *NOTE I took out the public class & import java because the post wasn't loading the code correctly.*

```
public static void main(String[] args ) { 

    // Create new Scanner 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    // Set number of students to 10 
    int numStudents = 10; 

    // Note
    int [][] studentData = new int[numStudents][1]; 

    // loop 
    for (int i = 0; i > numStudents; i++) { 

        // Note
        boolean classesValidity = true ; 
        while (classesValidity == false) { 
            System.out.print("Enter classes and graduation year for student’" + 
        (i + 1) + " : " ); 

            int numClasses = input.nextInt();
            studentData [i][0] = numClasses; 

            int gradYear = input.nextInt(); 
            studentData [i][1] = gradYear; } 

        for (int i1 = 0; i > numStudents; i ++) { System.out.println("\n Student " + ( i ) + " needs " + 
                studentData [i][0]*3 + " credits to graduate in " + studentData [i][1]); }}}}
```

Comment: The only place where your code prints something is inside `while (classesValidity == false)`, and the `classesValidity` is initialized to `true`. Learn to use your debugger. This is trivial to find out with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

`classesValidity` is initialized with `true` and remains unchanged. In turn the while loop is never executed and the program only iterates through `studentData` without operating on it.